# I have created a table view in swift using xib but it shows an error when I run the app

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

```
import UIKit

class NewOrdersViewControllers: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

    var items = ["WE","Heart","Swift"]
    @IBOutlet var tableView:UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.items.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")! as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.row]

        return cell


    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
```

It shows the error when I run the app. I have created a `table view` in swift using xib but  it shows the following error :

> NSArgumentException: '-[UIView tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7c9a6ed0""

Comment: work perfect for me. try clean project and run it again

Comment: I think you connected tableview's IBOutlet with UIView thats why its happening. So please check your IBOutlet connection in XIB.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure, you have given `DataSource` and `Delegate` to UITableView

```
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self
```

You define `numberOfRows` in 'numberOfSections`. Replace the below code with mine:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.items.count
}
```

**Change to below:**

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.items.count
}
```

Comment: The default value for numberOfSections is 1, so it is not necessary to return the number of sections explicitly

Comment: Also, consider separating your data source from your table view if you're planning on creating something larger than the example code given

Answer (score 1):

I think you have not set the delegate and the datasource for your tableView which happens to come form the xib . This is a common that people when they use UITableView. 
Set the delegate and the datasource for your tableview using swift syntax for the following objective-c code

```
self.tableView.delegate = self 
self.tableView.dataSource = self
```

**These statements should be in your viewDidLoad method.** Though the first is not compulsory if you dont want to handle the taps from the user on the cells. you have to write the second one for the display of information.

Tell me if something else is required.

Cheers.

Comment: Why "some value"? Also note that OP is not writing his code in Obj-C.

Comment: Edited... Sorry . Mistake rectified .. :)

Comment: Well ... hmmm... I am the one who answered the question and you are writing that in my answer. I would appreciate keeping in mind the principle of natural justice .. that my answer should be upvoted and accepted @RakeshMohan .Upvote is want I desire. :| . If my answer worked for you , upvote the answer please

Comment: Sorry for that @LearneriOS. I am new to stackoverflow. My reputation is below 15 so I would not be able to upvote the answer you have provided I guess, But thank you for your valuable feedback.

Comment: Hi @BR41N-FCK .. do you mind removing the downvote as the from the above comment the answer has worked for the OP and it is misleading that the answer is wrong.. :|

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're receiving indicates you've set the `dataSource` property of the `tableView` to the view, instead of the `viewController` to which you've added the `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` et al methods.